# new google.maps.LatLng(var) return (NaN,NaN)

Tags: jquery, google-maps

Already i have co ordinate in a hidden form .

```
var coordinate=$k('#input_hidden_coordinate').val();
//it returns valid 8.48749, 76.94862
var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(coordinate);
alert(latlng);
```

Above alert (NaN,NAN) instead of (8.48749, 76.94862)

Comment: There is no relation between lat,lng and coordinate in the code sample you provided.

Comment: why is $k it should be just $('#input_hidden_coordinate').val();

Comment: Perhaps if you split the 2 numbers and give 2 variables to the LatLng-function . I think with that code you give 1 variable to the LatLng function which is why it gives you an error.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jquery javascript google maps: getting coordinates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13285042/jquery-javascript-google-maps-getting-coordinates)

Answer (score 3):

Probably it does not work because coordinate is a string, whereas  google.maps.LatLng() will accept a pair of numeric values. Try this:

```
var coordinate=$k('#input_hidden_coordinate').val().split(',');
var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(coordinate[0],coordinate[1]);
alert(latlng);
```

Answer (score 2):

The object accepts two arguments, not one.

new google.maps.LatLng($lat, $lng)

not

new google.maps.LatLng($coords)

The other answer said this but I didn't understand it until I saw it explained like this on another page.